# CMake Export Package Not Working As Expected

Tags: cmake

I am working through learning CMake's install commands. I have it pretty much figured out for executables. For libraries there are few additional steps to build and install the required CMake scripts so the library can be used in the following scenarios.

1. Find and link the library from the local build generated by the current CMake project.
2. Find and link the library from a common installation location. This is required by 3rd party CMake projects that don't build the library.

I want to build a library called `FooBar`. `FooBar` is linked to an executable called `App`, that is defined in the same CMake project as `FooBar`.

Here are my CMake files and project structure.

```
<project-root>
    |-app
    |   |-src
    |   |   |-main.cpp
    |   |
    |   |-CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |-lib
    |   |-include
    |   |   |-FooBar.h
    |   |
    |   |-src
    |   |   |-FooBar.cpp
    |   |
    |   |-CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |-CMakeLists.txt
```

```
# File: <project-root>/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(SampleProject VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

```
# File: <project-root>/app/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

set(TARGET_NAME "App")

find_package(FooBar REQUIRED)

set(IMPL_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
)

add_executable(
    ${TARGET_NAME}
        ${IMPL_FILES}
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${TARGET_NAME} 
        PRIVATE
            FooBar
)

install(
    TARGETS
        ${TARGET_NAME}
    DESTINATION
        bin
)
```

```
# File: <project-root>/lib/CMakeLists.txt

set(LIB_NAME FooBar)
set(CMAKE_CXX_VERSION 11)

set(IMPL_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Lib.cpp
)

set(PUBLIC_DEFI_FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Lib.h
)

add_library(
    ${LIB_NAME}
        STATIC
            ${IMPL_FILES}
)

target_include_directories(
    ${LIB_NAME}
        PUBLIC
            $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
            $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

set_target_properties(
    ${LIB_NAME}
        PROPERTIES 
            PUBLIC_HEADER
                ${PUBLIC_DEFI_FILES}
)

install(
    TARGETS
        ${LIB_NAME}
    EXPORT
        ${LIB_NAME}Targets
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)

install(
    EXPORT 
        ${LIB_NAME}Targets 
    FILE 
        ${LIB_NAME}Config.cmake 
    DESTINATION
        lib/cmake/${LIB_NAME}
)

# I am under the impression these are needed for other targets in the
# current project to be able to use "find_package(FooBar)". I also
# think that "CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY" needs to not be set.
message(STATUS "CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY: ${CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY}")
export(
    EXPORT
        ${LIB_NAME}Targets
    FILE 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_NAME}Config.cmake
)
export(PACKAGE ${LIB_NAME})
```

To generate build files I run

```
# Clean project directory.
mkdir _build
cd _build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<project-root>/_dist
```

and I get the following error.

```
-- CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY: 
CMake Error at app/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindFooBar.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "FooBar", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FooBar" with any
  of the following names:

    FooBarConfig.cmake
    foobar-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "FooBar" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "FooBar_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "FooBar"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Running the above command a second time yields the same error message. I should not see that message because these two lines

```
export(
    EXPORT
        ${LIB_NAME}Targets
    FILE 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_NAME}Config.cmake
)
export(PACKAGE ${LIB_NAME})
```

should generate `_build/FooBar/FooBarConfig.cmake` and add it to the search path for packages seen by `App`.

If I remove the `app` sub-directory, build and install `FooBar` to `_dist`, and then re-add `app`, I do not get the error. Even if I clear out `_build` and generate build files from scratch, I don't get the error. How is CMake finding my local install config script, but not the one in the build directory? Am I doing something wrong or does anyone have any idea why this might not work?

Comment: What **exactly** doesn't expected? The error you get on the first run? Or the absence of the error in next runs? The reason of the error is pretty clear from the error message: you have no `FooBarConfig.cmake` file when run `find_package`. After the first successful run, you create that file and place it in registry. So you got no error after that.

Comment: I will reword the question to clear up the confusion.

Comment: If you interpret (right!) your app following the first scenario: "Find and link the library from the local build generated by the current CMake project.", then such app doesn't require any `find_package` call: it may use target created with `add_library` in the library's `CMakeLists.txt`. Command `export` is needed for other scenario: "Find and link the library from a common **build** location.". That is, when an app wants to use a library, which is *built* **by someone else**, but **not installed**.

Comment: Then what is the benefit of the `export(PACKAGE FooBar)` CMake command?

Comment: I already know the linking will work without the `find_package` command. My question is why it it does not work with the `find_package` command in conjunction with the `export(PACKAGE FooBar)` command. Hope I have made it clear what I am asking.

Comment: An example of what your second scenario might be useful as I don't see the purpose of that usage scenario.

Comment: As far as I understand `export()` command, until the project has been **successfully built**, its exported files are *not usable* for other project: one cannot link with the library file until it is created. This is a reason why you cannot use exported files from the same project: `find_package` cannot detect files which are not created yet. I don't know when an export file is created (and registered), but I think it isn't created until **successful configuration**. (And it cannot be used until successful build, see explanations above).

Comment: As for advantages of `export()` against `install(EXPORT)`, one of them is that the project needn't to be **installed** before its export file can be used. Specific usage see in the [documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/export.html) (it is related with host executables needed for cross-compiling). I am not very undestand the meaning of `export()` command. And my opinion is that one needn't to use `export()` for his/her project until he/she has truly understand **usefulness** of this command **specifically for the project**.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. Export is for very specific use case which most people don't need. Thank you for the clarification.